# Fetch multiple table value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I using the code for fetching the data in two tables in cakephp.

> *var $belongsTo = array(
>           'Menuitem' => array(
>               'className'     => 'Menuitem',
>               'foreignKey'    => 'menu'
>           )     );*

menu is the index key in both tables but it is showing the first table data showing proper but in second table showing null values.

```
**'Menu' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'menuName' => 'awefawef',
            'restID' => '2',
            'menu' => '41066',
            'status' => '0'
        ),
        'Menuitem' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'menuID' => null,
            'sectionID' => null,
            'itemName' => null,
            'itemPrice' => null,
            'itemDescription' => null,
            'menu' => null,
            'status' => null
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Menu' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'menuName' => 'awefawef',
            'restID' => '2',
            'menu' => '17717',
            'status' => '0'
        ),
        'Menuitem' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'menuID' => null,
            'sectionID' => null,
            'itemName' => null,
            'itemPrice' => null,
            'itemDescription' => null,
            'menu' => null,
            'status' => null
        )**
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

In cakePHP the above join will not work because you are NOT following name conventions.

So in your Menu model create one function and write below code:

```
$options = array(
        'conditions' => array(**YOUR CONDITIONS**),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'Menuitem',  
                'table' => ‘menuitems’,
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Menuitem.menuID = Menu.id',
                ),
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array(“**Your Fields**”)
    );
$returnData = $this->find('all',$options);
```

Thanks